# How to get the javascript range object for the selected text in UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, uiwebview, range

I have simple UIWebView with loaded html. i want to save the javascript range object in the server side for a later use. any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use my Rangy library's [Serializer](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/SerializerModule) module ([demo](http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/serializer.html)).

Comment: thanks.. but xPath was the solution for me.. i had problem with serializer; taking so much time( i was waiting for 4 second and finally don't have the result).

Comment: @ElyesJlassi: Fair enough. Just fyi, Rangy's serializer is massively quicker if you tell it not to calculate a checksum of the document state: `rangy.serializeSelection(rangy.getSelection(), true);`

Comment: @OhDannyBoy: I've seen it working in a `UIWebView`. The problem is that unless the selection is already visible, programmatically changing the selection has no visible effect.

Comment: @TimDown Thx for the tip, it fixed my issue! But, can u explain the use of 'checksum'?

Comment: @sk8terboi87ツ: The idea is to check whether the DOM is in the same state when serializing and deserializing. When deserializing, Rangy calculates a checksum for the DOM and if it's different from the checksum in the serialized selection, it knows the deserialization is likely to fail and bails out.

Comment: @TimDown: Oh, I get it... So, its like verifying our selection is still valid. 
BTW Thanks for the awesome plugin! :)